# Erro na Paginação PHP

Tags: php, paginação

Galera, estou com um probleminha na paginação de um sistema que estou desenvolvendo.
Quando eu busco o resultando no banco de dados, o link para passar para a próxima pagina, ou não link ou fica oculto.
Eu descobri que o  problema está nessa linha: `$quant_pg = ceil ($sql / $limite) -1;`

alguém pode me ajudar a resolver o problema, já quebrei cabeça que só aqui!

Aqui está o codigo da que visualiza o resultado do Banco:

```
<body>
<center><h2> Lojas Cadastradas </h2></center>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table">
    <tr class="linha">
        <td class="linha" width="20%" align="center"><b>Codigo da Loja</b></td>
        <td class="linha" align="center"><b>Nome da Loja</b></td>
    </tr>
<?php
require 'processos/config.php';
require 'processos/connection.php';
require 'processos/database.php';


    $limite = 5; // Quantos registros por página vai ser mostrado
    if( isset( $_GET['pagina'] ) && (int)$_GET['pagina'] >= 0) {
    $pagina = (int)$_GET['pagina'];
    }
    else {
          $pagina = 0;
    }

    $offset = $limite * $pagina;

  //LÊ DADOS DO BANCO
    $lojas = DBRead ("lojas", "ORDER BY cod_loja ASC LIMIT $limite OFFSET $offset", "id_lojas, cod_loja, nome_loja");

  foreach ($lojas as $lj) {

        ?>
    <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" onclick="DoNav('altera_loja.php?id=<?php echo $lj['id_lojas'];?>');">
        <td class="linha" align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $lj['cod_loja'];?></td>
        <td class="linha espaco" valign="middle"><?php echo $lj['nome_loja']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
<?php
  require "paginacao.php";
?>
</body>
```

a baixo segue o código da paginação;

```
<?php
$sql = DBRead ("lojas");

$quant_pg = ceil ($sql / $limite) -1;
$quant_pg ++;

var_dump($sql);
//echo "$sql";


// Verifica se esta na primeira página, se nao estiver ele libera o link para anterior
if ( @$_GET['pg'] > 0) {
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pg=".(@$_GET['pg']-1)." class=pg ><b>&laquo; Anterior</b></a>";
} else {
echo "<font color=#CCCCCC>&laquo; anterior </font>";
}

// Faz aparecer os numeros das página entre o ANTERIOR e PROXIMO

for($i_pg=1; $i_pg<$quant_pg;$i_pg++) {
// Verifica se a página que o navegante esta e retira o link do número para identificar visualmente

if (@$_GET['pg'] == ($i_pg-1)) {
echo "&nbsp;<span class=pgoff>[$i_pg]</span>&nbsp;";
} else {
$i_pg2 = $i_pg-1;
echo "&nbsp;<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pg=$i_pg2 class=pg><b>$i_pg</b></a>&nbsp;";
}
}

// Verifica se esta na ultima página, se nao estiver ele libera o link para próxima
if ((@$_GET['pg']+2) < $quant_pg) {
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pg=".(@$_GET['pg']+1)." class=pg ><b>próximo &raquo;</b></a>";
} else {
echo " <font color=#CCCCCC> -- próximo &raquo;</font>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Tem muita coisa aí pra melhorar... dá uma olhada [neste exemplo de paginação](http://www.tocadigital.com.br/2012/05/classe-completa-com-paginacao-de-registros-e-consulta-ao-banco-de-dados-mysql/). Ou [este exemplo](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928), um pouco mais robusto.

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = DBRead ("lojas"); 
$quant_pg = ceil ($sql / $limite) -1;`

DBread parece retornar um resultset pra dentro da variável $sql, mas você está usando ele no seu código como se fosse a quantidade de linhas. Será que tá certo isso?

Dá um echo tanto no $sql quanto no $limite pra ver quais valores estão vindo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta é uma forma de fazer isso funcionar:

```
class Paginacao
{

    private $limit=3;
    private $proxima='<b>Pr&oacute;xima &raquo;</b>';
    private $anterior='<b>&laquo; Anterior</b>';
    private $pagina="";
    private $getPage="";
    private $idPagination = "";
    private $numeroPaginasIntermediarias = 4;

    public function __construct($getPage = 'index.php?page=', $id = 'paginacao')
    {
        $this->getPage = $getPage;
        $this->idPagination = $id;      
    }

    public function setTotalperPage($total)
    {
        $this->limit = $total;
    }   

    public function getInitial($pagina,$max)
    {

        $this->limit =$max;

        if ($pagina == "") {  
           $pagina = 1;  
        } 
        $inicio = $pagina - 1;
        $inicio = $this->limit * $inicio;
        return $inicio;
    }

    public function pagination($total = null, $pagina = null) {
        $max = $this->limit;
        $tags = ''; 
        if ($max!=0) {
            $tags .= "<div align=\"center\" id=\"".$this->idPagination."\">";
            // Calculando pagina anterior
               $menos = $pagina - 1;
            // Calculando pagina posterior
               $mais = $pagina + 1;

            // 
            $pgs = (int) ceil($total / $max);

            if ($pgs > 1 ) {
                if ($menos >0) { 
                  $tags.= "<a href=\"{$this->getPage}{$menos}\" class=\"navegacao\">".$this->anterior."</a> "; 
                }

                if (($pagina - $this->numeroPaginasIntermediarias) < 1 ) {
                  $anterior = 1;
                } else { 
                  $anterior = $pagina-$this->numeroPaginasIntermediarias;
                }

                if (($pagina + $this->numeroPaginasIntermediarias) > $pgs ) {
                    $posterior = $pgs;
                } else {
                    $posterior = $pagina + $this->numeroPaginasIntermediarias;
                }

                for ($i = $anterior; $i <= $posterior; $i++) {
                    if ($i != $pagina) {
                       $tags.= " <a href=\"{$this->getPage}{$i}\" class=\"pg\"><b>$i</b></a>";
                    } else {
                      $tags.= " <span class=\"pgoff\">$i</span>";
                    }
                }

                if ($mais <= $pgs) { 
                    $tags.= " <a href=\"{$this->getPage}{$mais}\" class=\"pg\">".$this->proxima."</a>";
                }
            }
                $tags.= "</div>";
                return $tags;
        }

    }

}


$paginacao = new Paginacao($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pg=', 'minha_paginacao');

$max = 20;  
$inicio = $paginacao->getInitial(1, $max);

$SQL = DBRead("lojas");
// aqui você traz o total usando seus métodos
$total_registros = $this->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lojas");
// e use seus método de query passando "offset" e "limite por pagina"
$collection = $this->db->query($SQL." LIMIT $inicio, $max");     

foreach ($collection as $data) {
    echo $data['campo1'].'<br>';
}
echo $paginacao->pagination($total_registros, $inicio);
```